# Enable communication between two Android apps via custom permissions

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions

One of my Android applications needs some features that are "dangerous" when it comes to permissions. They require some permissions such as "Internet access" which are critical in combination with private data.

This is why I want to create a separate "Add-on", i.e. a second app that provides these permission-critical features. So if users want them, they can install the add-on, but the main app will still work without those permissions.

Using a `sharedUserId` would obviously be the easiest solution, but adding this afterwards, when lots of users use the app already, could cause serious problems. Wouldn't this mean that the app can't access its own data any longer?

So I have to choose another approach. ContentProviders are something that I try to avoid, because they're too complex for this simple need in my opinion.

I thought custom permissions could solve the issue. Can they? I've added the following permission declaration to both the main app as well as the add-on as a child to the `manifest` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.my.package.ADDON"
    android:label="@string/permission_title"
    android:description="@string/permission_description"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.PERSONAL_INFO"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Furthermore, both manifest files have got this part now:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.my.package.ADDON"></uses-permission>
```

The add-on app includes an `IntentService` that has the following attribute now:

```
android:permission="com.my.package.ADDON"
```

Shouldn't this do the job so that I can call the add-on's `IntentService` from my main app via this code?

```
Intent addonIntent = new Intent();
addonIntent.setClassName("com.my.package", "com.my.package.MyService");
startService(addonIntent);
```

Unfortunately, this call always fails with the following exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16721): java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.mypackage.addon/.MyService } without permission com.mypackage.permission.ADDON
```

What did I do wrong? Thank you very much in advance!

**Addition #1 - Add-on manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      package="com.mypackage.addon">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.mypackage.permission.ADDON"
        android:label="@string/permission_title"
        android:description="@string/permission_description"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.PERSONAL_INFO"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="com.mypackage.permission.ADDON"
    android:exported="true">
    <service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".MyService" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

**Addition #2 - main app manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      package="com.mypackage.mainapp">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.mypackage.permission.ADDON"
        android:label="@string/permission_title"
        android:description="@string/permission_description"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.PERSONAL_INFO"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mypackage.permission.ADDON"></uses-permission>
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="MyApp">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you get it work finally? I'm looking for something very similar. Need to optionally add Internet permission to existing app with no SharedUserId...

Comment: Did you get it work finally? I'm looking for something very similar. Need to optionally add Internet permission to existing app with no SharedUserId...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Wouldn't this mean that the app can't access its own data any longer?

Correct.

> I've added the following permission

I would dump the `permission-group`, as that should not be necessary.

> Furthermore, both manifest files have got this part now

Only the one calling your `IntentService` might need that.

> Shouldn't this do the job so that I can call the add-on's IntentService from my main app via this code?

Not if that `IntentService` is not exported. Make sure that your `IntentService` either has an `<intent-filter>` or `android:exported="true"`. I would recommend going the `<intent-filter>` route, so you can declare and use a custom action string, so you get away from hard-coding package and class names in the client app.

[Here is a directory with two sample projects](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/CPProxy) using this basic approach, though in my case the communications are based on a secured `ContentProvider` rather than a secured `IntentService`. The concept is the same, though, and so with these minor tweaks, I would expect what you are doing to work just fine.

Comment: Thank you! The reason why I didn't set `android:exported="true"` is that Eclipse says: Exported services don't need permissions. So I thought that the main app needs the permissions then when the add-on's service is exported. True?

Comment: @MarcoW.: "So I thought that the main app needs the permissions then when the add-on's service is exported. True?" -- correct. However, the add-on does not need the `<uses-permission>`, only the `<permission>` and the `android:permission`.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to enable communication in both directions, I just left that out here. If the main app requires the permissions, the add-on is not useful anymore, as I wanted to "outsource" the permission-critical features. So the only chance I have is to use the same `sharedUserId` in the main app and in the add-on, right?

Comment: @MarcoW.: "Yes, but I wanted to enable communication in both directions" -- no problem. Pass a `Messenger`, or a `PendingIntent`, in your command you supply to `startService()`. The former should not require any particular permissions; the latter might indeed require both sides to have `<uses-permission>` and `android:permission`, to defend both directions of the communication. "So the only chance I have is to use the same sharedUserId in the main app and in the add-on, right?" -- I sure hope not. Nobody outside of a device manufacturer should seriously consider `sharedUserId`.

Comment: Why not? As it is secured via package signing, and if you only want to provide an add-on to your own application, I see no reason why you shouldn't use `sharedUserId`. A `ContentProvider` would be total overkill. Trying to sum up this topic: I can only start another app's service if the latter is exported. And if so, the calling app needs all the permissions. Right? But: `This attribute is not the only way to limit the exposure of a service to other applications. You can also use a permission to limit the external entities that can interact with the service (see the permission attribute).`

Comment: @MarcoW.: "Why not?" -- for starters, Google recommends against it. Second is the issue you raised in your question: one wrong move, and you are locked out of your data for existing users. " can only start another app's service if the latter is exported. And if so, the calling app needs all the permissions." -- the calling app needs to request the permission via `<uses-permission>`. "But" -- your "but" is referring to the receiving side. The caller has `<uses-permission>`, the recipient has `android:permission`, and both have `<permission>` (for custom permissions).

Comment: Ah, this was a misunderstanding! I don't want to give the main app the native permission `Internet`. So I want to put these features into the add-on app and give the permission `Internet` to the add-on app only. But when I export the service, Eclipse says the add-on doesn't need `Internet`, only the main app. And if this is so, my add-on would be useless. Of course, I have to set `<uses-permission>` for my custom permission.

Comment: @MarcoW.: Eclipse is easily confused. And, since I can't see your manifests from way over here, I cannot comment as to whether what Eclipse is telling you is correct or merely it being confused. Make sure your add-on actually uses something that needs the `INTERNET` permission, though.